# JavaScript Iterating through Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just started using Firebase and I am having trouble iterating through database objects (i.e in JSON).

Here is a sample data

```
const _ = require ('underscore');
var data ={
  "posts": {
    "-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY": {
      "author": "gracehop",
      "title": "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
    },
    "-JRHTHaKuITFIhnj02kE": {
      "author": "alanisawesome",
      "title": "The Turing Machine"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to display it in a table eg:

```
return <table>
    <tr>
        <td>author</td>
        <td>title</td>
    </tr>
    {data.map(k=>{
    return <tr key={k}>
        <td>{k.author}</td>
        <td>{k.title}</td>
    </tr>
    }).bind(this)}
</table>
```

Previously i used a completely different architecture (psql + python) and objects were being returned in a different way eg:

```
const _ = require ('underscore');
var data ={
  0: {
    "-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY": {
      "author": "gracehop",
      "title": "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
    },
    1: {
      "author": "alanisawesome",
      "title": "The Turing Machine"
    }
  }
}
```

And the code worked. However the Object.map doesnot seem to work with a text value.

I would like to know best way to iterate through these data. I have tried to  used underscore's mapObject feature, forEach, each and i am having difficutly finding proper documentation to iterate these kind of datas. Any suggestion to appreciate this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using some kind of HTML pre-processor? That's not how you declare a `<script>`.

Comment: @4castle I suspect he's using React, that's how Javascript code is escaped inside JSX.

Comment: It's not *escaped* -_-

Comment: You can use whatever word to describe it, what I mean is just you can stop writing XML and start writing Javascript again.

Comment: Actually, i am using React, i just copied some relevant snippets.

Answer (score 0):

`map` is an Array method; what you have is an object. You can use `Object.values(data)` to get the values of the object as an array, so you can then do `Object.values(data).map`.

If you can't use `Object.values` due to browser compatibility issues, you can also use `Object.keys(data)` to get an array of keys. You can then do a `map` to retrieve each value, something like `Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key])` and you will end up with the array of values you want.